# Facebook user-context-id and id of the User are same?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the facebook mutual-friends between me and my friend in Java Spring framework.

I can get the friends of mine who are all installed the app. But unable to get the mutual friends.

My doubt is what is user-context-id .. The user id and user-context-id are same.

If yes i am getting the Exception.
{**user-context-id**}/mutual_friends

Please anyone help me on this what is user-context-id and how can we get for my friends

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accesstoken, Version.LATEST);
User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class, Parameter.with("fields", "email,name,locale"));
        Connection<User> friends = null;
        String customerId = user.getId();
        String customerName = user.getName();
        String customerMail = user.getEmail();

    Connection<User> friends = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/{user-id of the target person}/mutual_friends", User.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

`user-context-id` and `user-id` are not the same.

In Graph API:

- **user-context-id:** Social context for a person
- **user-id:** The /{user-id} node returns a single user. (A user represents a person on Facebook.)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct API call to get mutual friends between you and a friend:

```
/[id-of-friend]?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)
```

Or:

```
/[id-of-friend]?fields=context{mutual_friends}
```

You have to use your User Access Token for this, of course. And i assume you know that you can only get mutual friends who authorized your App too.

Btw, this is how to get the "Context ID", if needed:

```
/[id-of-friend]?fields=context{id}
```

Example:

```
facebookClient.fetchObject("831925293625800", User.class, Parameter.with("fields", "cont‌​ext.fields(mutual_fr‌​iends)"));
```

Comment: Dear luschn, with your point i have end up with the following results Steps tried:: 1) Connection<User> friends  = facebookClient1.fetchConnection("/{user-id}?fields=context{id}", User.class); but it says active access_token must be needed so i use the user access_token to connect the facebook. At last i got OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {1351426911589218}. What should i do actually . please give me your suggestions

Comment: what for would you need the user context? you can just get the mutual friends directly with the first api call in my answer.

Comment: Using the first api call i am getting this error                                     
Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#803) **Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {831925293625800}** (code 803, subcode null). But the current user and target person are friends and they both authorised user_friends permission. Both are using the app . But why i am unable to get mutual friends . Please point out my errors

Comment: is that an app scoped id from the same app? works fine for me with those...

Comment: i REALLY hope you did not put the curly brackets into your code though...this would be the example api call: /1351426911589218?fields=context

Comment: no i put correct **friends = facebookClient.fetchConnection("/{831925293625800}?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)", User.class);**

Comment: that is NOT correct....please read my last comment again and remove those curly brackets...

Comment: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Syntax error "Expected end of string instead of "?"." at character 30: context.fields(mutual_friends)?access_token=[current-user-access-token] (code 2500, subcode null)  but i didnt append token this is my code                  facebookClient.fetchConnection("/831925293625800?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)", User.class);

Comment: according to the docs, you are using the sdk in a wrong way. this could work: facebookClient.fetchObject("831925293625800", User.class, Parameter.with("fields", "cont‌​ext.fields(mutual_fr‌​iends)"));

Comment: you may want to read the docs of an sdk before using it: https://github.com/restfb/restfb

Comment: yeah i red, but there is no document for mutual_friends. Of course i got friends list of the logged in user. But i am unable to get the mutual_friends tried with many solutions. Got different kind of errors for every try .

Comment: so did you try without the curly brackets, and with the code in my comment?

Comment: yeah correct but still i am not getting the exception. Can u pls suggest any sample code or any website for facebook mutual friends java spring framwork

Comment: "not getting the exception" - that is a good thing, is it not? so what is the current error with my code suggestion?

Comment: this is the error OAuthException: Syntax error "Expected end of string instead of "?"." at character 4: cont??ext.fields(mutual_fr??iends)?access_token=EAAUPJYNIkfIBAAHsoalkjj4e7fmo4kIV1KXp1hezDLQerZAIgmc4tJgzbdfNZBulHgYFMvPbAeQrlPHwZBIstqRJsxkYjpuKlZAucbQnJprkG1dN4jp9Q8rYqFyneXQiJ0cdEShFmUIrZArZCTjvc9Sk4UCfxoATZCtqKZBRGb9RxAZDZD (code 2500, subcode null) but i didnt add anything and i didnt add logged in user  access token also but i am getting this error  friends2 = facebookClient.fetchObject("/1351426911589218?fields=cont‌​ext.fields(mutual_fr‌​iends)", User.class);

Comment: so you still did not use the correct code from my comment...the error message tells you exactly what the problem is, why not use MY code? (which is basically the code from the sdk docs)

Comment: i have added the code to my answer. make sure you know what the difference to your code is, and make sure you understand what that error means.